# How to compute the Eigen values of diagonal plus a rank one matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I'm trying to find information on the eigenvalues of an n×n matrix $A$ such that

$A=D+J$
Where $D$ is some complex valued diagonal matrix, and $J$ is a rank one matrix, $J = uu^T$.
How to compute the eigen values of $A$ in this case?

Comment: Perhaps this might be useful: [Bunch–Nielsen–Sorensen formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunch%E2%80%93Nielsen%E2%80%93Sorensen_formula)?

Comment: Questions about eigenvalues after rank one updates have been asked several times on MO previously; please search for them; most likely they already answer your question.

Comment: Just to avoid possible missunderstandings: do you assume the perturbation $J$ to be a *general* rank-$1$ matrix (which would be of the form $J = uv^T$ rather than $J = uu^T$), or do you really wish $J$ to be of the form $J = uu^T$ (and thus symmetric)?

Comment: Yes, I assume $J = uu^T$

Comment: My question above is not answered by any of the previous  questions asked here.  Since the previous questions here assume D to be an identity matrix and my case D being diagonal with all entries distinct. Could someone have an answer for this case?